# What serif/calligraphy fonts have a lot of discretionary ligatures?

Tags: typography, font-recommendation

I'm looking for typefaces that have a lot of discretionary ligatures, more specifically a serif or calligraphic font of the fancy/classical sort.

I am already aware of:

- Mrs. Eaves
- DTL Fleischmann
- Hoefler Text
- Requiem

Am I missing any big names?

Comment: Zapfino has a lot of ligatures, but maybe not the sort of calligraphy you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Calligraphic:**

- Bickham Script Pro
- Caflisch Script Pro
- Brioso Pro
- Ex Ponto Pro
- Poetica Std
- Sanvito Pro
- Silentium Pro
- Waters Titling Pro
- Zapfino --- see my article on it here: http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb24-2/tb77adams.pdf

**Text fonts w/ extensive alternates:**

- Arno Pro
- Minion Pro

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I clearly understand "alternate" ligatures, however, probably you will like these 3 fonts (they have "Discretionary Ligatures" -

[ITC Dyadis](http://www.fonts.com/font/itc/itc-dyadis/complete-family-pack)

[ITC Founder's Caslon](http://www.fonts.com/font/itc/itc-founders-caslon/complete-family-pack)

[ITC Rennie Mackintosh](http://www.fonts.com/font/itc/itc-rennie-mackintosh/complete-family-pack)